# How does OEM Windows boot icon customization work?

Tags: windows, bios, operating-systems, icons, post

In almost every post-Windows 8 laptop or tablet I see, the icon displayed by the OS above the spinning dots is customized by the OEM. The same happens on my ASUS motherboard, where the Windows logo is replaced with ASUS's on boot. What I find rather weird is that it is not apparently stored within the OS: any Windows copy I start on my machine shows ASUS's logo on boot, and my motherboard even has a feature that lets me change the image.

To apply the change, I need to generate a custom BIOS binary blob using the provided tool and flash it using "*EZ Update Utility*". After it is done, both the ASUS P.O.S.T. logo and the Windows boot icon are replaced with the custom picture I chose, while on macOS (on the same machine) a regular Apple logo is shown.

In the BIOS it lets me chose "Logo size" which, if set to "Maximum" makes Windows display its own original icon (blue Win10 logo) on boot. Apparently also, these icons have trasparency.

**How is this feature called? Where is the image stored? How does it work? How does it get implemented?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of  ACPI system dscription tables which UEFI sets before it loads Windows which is why you can change the UEFI and it takes effect on the Windows boot logo. The logo would be loaded into memory by the UEFI and then pointed to in the ACPI tables. The OS then reads these tables and loads the image. It is stored in an area of memory that is only allocated for UEFI which is why its not supported unless using UEFI.